# Encoding ML classification features that are relative to the dependant categories

Tags: machine-learning, feature-engineering, one-hot-encoding

I have a classification problem with three classes A, B & C.

I have features x1, x2 and x3 that represent my data items. But I also have a fourth feature that represents a similarity between my data item and each one of A, B & C.

My question is, how to encode this similarity feature given that it is relative to each of A, B & C.

My guess would be to have three similarity features sA, sB and sC. One for each category in the style of one-hot-encoding. So my resulting features are:

x1, x2, x3, sA, sB, sC

Questions:

- Is this approach problematic in any way?
- Is there an alternative?
- Is there a name for this kind of encoding?

Comment: Is this similarity given already as part of the data, or you have computed it yourself starting from the initial features and the labels?

Comment: The similarity is computed from the features (but not x1,x2,x3) of the data item and the features of the label.

The data item is a geometry and it has geometrical features. The label also represents a geometry which has geometrical features. I can calculate a geometric similarity between the data item and each label. I'd like to combine this with my 'regular' features (x1,x2,x3).

Comment: And how are you gonna build these similarity features for the unseen data, where the labels are not available?